# DirectX compilation error: error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, directx

I am learning DirectX11 but can't get around this problem when compiling the project:

> Error 1 error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 1126 5 DirectX

I am using Visual Studio 2013, DirectX 11, and the Effects framework.

I've searched the internet and did every single thing that they suggested such as properly setting the HLSL Compiler with fx as shader type and 5_0 as shader model. The include, lib and bin directories are properly set. There is a question on the topic here but it's not answered properly so I figured someone could explain how to overcome it now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try compile the file directly using ``FXC`` rather than using MSBuild to see what happens. Be sure to see [Effects 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11).

Answer (score 1):

You  should configure  HLSL  file correctly.  It  means  shader model(3.0, 4.0, 5.0), shader  types(PS, VS, GS, or general just FX(with entry point if u got it) ....).  fxc.exe  is  HLSL compiler  which  compiles  your  shader  code, but  it seems entire  compiler is not  targeted on right shader file(s).  As well error  says to you  that compiler execution had been exited with result 1 , now you  should  click on shader(s) file with right mouse  button and configure your shader that's it. 
Hope this  helps.

P.S. Oh and which  version of Windows  do you use ?  because it's  matter  how would  you talking with DirectX  SDK ?  This is important.