# Errors compiling shader - DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx, shader, dxgi

I have been struggling with some compilers errors since yesterday, trying to compile a DirectX11 project. Everything was working well until i created and defined an object to render. I added, for this, a shader (type effect).

The compiler told me that " "fxc.exe" exited with code 1".
To solve this, i followed this answer : [DirectX compilation error: error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935171/directx-compilation-error-error-msb6006-fxc-exe-exited-with-code-1)

Hence, i defined my HLSL compiler's shader model as :

```
Shader Model 5.0 (/5_0)
```

But after this, i still get some errors :

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\d3d11shader.h(68): error C3646: 'MinPrecision': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\d3d11shader.h(68): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\d3d11shader.h(235): error C3646: 'InterpolationMode': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\d3d11shader.h(235): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1275): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'DXGI_RGBA'
```

For the three last errors, i had them before but fixed them following the step 5-a of this MSDN page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx
But now these errors are back and i do not understand why. I did check the project properties again but the errors are still back.

I think these are some compiler errors, and i tried to fix it by following the step 6 of the above link but it did not work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 by the way.

Could anyone help me please ? I've really been searching for answers and trying to fix it but nothing seems to work for now.
Thank you.

Comment: You have not posted relevant code so how are we supposed to find out what's wrong in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely mixing the legacy DirectX SDK and the Windows 8.1 SDK incorrectly.  `D3D_MIN_PRECISION` is missing a definition which is defined in the Windows 8.1 SDK version of `d3dcommon.h` but *not* in the legacy DirectX SDK version.

Make sure your include/libs paths have the Windows 8.1 SDK listed first.

Make sure you are explicitly including `<d3d11.h>` before you include `<d3dx11.h>` to make sure you pick up the right version.

You might also want to explicitly include `<d3dcommon.h>` first as well.

> Ideally you'd just not use the legacy DirectX SDK at all in your project. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/).

Of course all this applies to your C++ code. The headers `d3d11shader.h` and `dxgi1_2.h` can't be included into HLSL shader code.

Comment: Thank you ! Just by including <d3d11.h> before <d3dx11.h> it solved all these errors ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Step 5b of the MSDN instructions :)